# Persist and fetch data in with block

Tags: python, python-3.x, persistence, python-asyncio

I have a situation - I'm using the `asyncio` package with Python 3.x, and persisting data in a `with` block, something like this:

```
test_repo = TestRepository()

with (yield from test_repo):
    res = yield from test_repo.get_by_lim_off(
            page_size=int(length),
            offset=start,
            customer_name=customer_name,
            customer_phone=customer_phone,
            return_type=return_type
        )
```

I need to get `res` data in the `with` block, but persistence and fetching data should happen when I exit from the `with` block. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow.
What is `TestRepository` class?

Comment: Are you saying you want to make asynchronous calls inside `__exit__`? If so, [that won't be supported until Python 3.5](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/).

Comment: @Andrew Svetlov: TestRepository() is a repository pattern for models layer, I just change its name. This class manages all model functionalities

Comment: Well, looks like you are really need for PEP 492 like @dano mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is only supported in Python 3.5+, via asynchronous context managers (`__aenter__`/`__aexit__`), and `async with`, both of which were added in [PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/):

```
class TestRepository:
   # All your normal methods go here

   async def __aenter__(self):
      # You can call coroutines here
      await self.some_init()

   async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc, tb):
      # You can call coroutines here
      await self.do_persistence()
      await self.fetch_data()


async def do_work():
    test_repo = TestRepository()

    async with test_repo:
        res = await test_repo.get_by_lim_off(
                page_size=int(length),
                offset=start,
                customer_name=customer_name,
                customer_phone=customer_phone,
                return_type=return_type
            )

 asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(do_work())
```

Prior to 3.5, you have to use a `try`/`finally` block with explicit calls to the init/cleanup coroutines, unfortunately:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def do_work():
    test_repo = TestRepository()

    yield from test_repo.some_init()
    try:
        res = yield from test_repo.get_by_lim_off(
                page_size=int(length),
                offset=start,
                customer_name=customer_name,
                customer_phone=customer_phone,
                return_type=return_type
            )
    finally:
        yield from test_repo.do_persistence()
        yield from test_repo.fetch_data()
```